# building like team viewer in c#

Tags: c#

i need to build an application like team viewer in c# , anyone have knowledge or documentation or links please help me ?

Comment: You mean, like writni you the code, or a complete project plan? That is totally beyond the scope of this site. Don' you have one or more specific questions?

Comment: not the code  mister ,  i said someone have links , ebooks or knowledge about how it works

Answer (score 1):

There's a [client API for TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/03/15/552288.aspx) which could be used to build such application.

Comment: Is it me, or you confused [Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/es/index.aspx) with [Team Fundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/tfs-overview-vs)...?